# Original reference for Binary star system orbital seperation decay rate due to GW emission

Tags: astrophysics, gravitational-waves, specific-reference, binary-stars

Could someone please point me in the direction of who first derived the equation for the orbital separation decay rate of two point masses in a binary system due to the emission of gravitational waves:

$$ \frac{dr}{dt} = -\frac{64}{5} \frac{G^3}{c^5} \frac{(m_1m_2)(m_1+m_2)}{r^3}. $$

I have found the equation in a couple of different textbooks (Gravitation: Foundations and Frontiers, Exploring Black Holes), but I cant seem to find who first derived it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this 1964 paper](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.136.B1224) by Peters was the first to do it for elliptical orbits (for which the formula is more complicated). Possibly circular orbits were done earlier by someone else. It follows from the quadrupole approximation for gravitational radiation.

In addition to deriving the rate at which the semimajor axis shrinks, this paper also derives the rate at which the eccentricity decreases, thereby circularizing the orbit.

Comment: Great, thank you